# Realm does not save data

Tags: swift, realm

I come here because I have an issue with Realm.

My Realm is empty, I have my Object "User", which is completed (id, name, etc...), and when I write it into the Realm, everything is good.

But when I request my object again, it exists, but is empty, no data... Do you know what's wrong?

Here is a small example of my code :

```
println("id: " + currentUser.id) // "id: 2"
Realm().write
    {
        println("id: " + currentUser.id) // "id: 2"
        Realm().add(currentUser)
}
var user = Realm().objects(User).first!
println("id: " + user.id) // "id: "
```

EDIT: I checked my database with RealmBrowser, and every fields are full, with the correct data... So why does my query fail?

Comment: Could you show more code than this little piece ? It could be useful to see how you populate your object before write it to Realm

Comment: Ok, after your edit, have you try to filter the results returns by Realm, just for trying. By Example in your case, write: `Realm().objects(User).filter("id == %d", currentUser.id).first`

Comment: Tried that, but it founds nil. I tried to loop on the Realm().objects(User), and it only loop once, with println("id: " + user.id) // "id: "

Comment: If it loop once, you will have a `user` fullfiled. Or I don't understand the problem ?

Answer (score 4):

I found my mistake, i accidentally forgot the "dynamic" modifier in front of every variables in my model "User".

Comment: With all of your code, That's should be possible to help you in this case ;)